# How to Load Data into Amazon Redshift via Python Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, boto3

In Amazon Redshift's [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-prereq.html), data is pulled from Amazon S3 and loaded into an Amazon Redshift Cluster utilizing SQLWorkbench/J. I'd like to mimic the same process of connecting to the cluster and loading sample data into the cluster utilizing [Boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/).

However in [Boto3's documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/redshift.html#Redshift.Client.create_cluster) of Redshift, I'm unable to find a method that would allow me to upload data into Amazon Redshift cluster.

I've been able to connect with Redshift utilizing Boto3 with the following code:

```python
client = boto3.client('redshift')
```

But I'm not sure what method would allow me to either create tables or upload data to Amazon Redshift the way it's done in the [tutorial with SQLWorkbenchJ](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-create-sample-db.html).

Comment: fwiw aws sdk for pandas (awswrangler) has suitable methods, for example [copy_from_files()](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.redshift.copy_from_files.html#awswrangler.redshift.copy_from_files)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go back to step 4 in that tutorial you linked. See where it shows you how to get the URL of the cluster? You have to connect to that URL with a PostgreSQL driver. The AWS SDKs such as Boto3 provide access to the AWS API. You need to connect to Redshift over a PostgreSQL API, just like you would connect to a PostgreSQL database on RDS.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now trying to figure out how to utilize SQLAlchemy instead SQLWorkbenchJ, which I'm having some difficulty utilizing (I may edit this question or create a new one).

Comment: If you have a new question, create a new question. Please don't edit an existing question to ask something new.

Comment: Use Aginity Workbench for Redshift for connecting to the cluster. It has much better UI and features, and is recommended by the AWS folks as well.

Answer (score 25):

Right, you need `psycopg2` Python module to execute COPY command.

My code looks like this:

```
import psycopg2
#Amazon Redshift connect string 
conn_string = "dbname='***' port='5439' user='***' password='***' host='mycluster.***.redshift.amazonaws.com'"  
#connect to Redshift (database should be open to the world)
con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string);
sql="""COPY %s FROM '%s' credentials 
      'aws_access_key_id=%s; aws_secret_access_key=%s'
       delimiter '%s' FORMAT CSV %s %s; commit;""" % 
      (to_table, fn, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,delim,quote,gzip)

#Here
#  fn - s3://path_to__input_file.gz
#  gzip = 'gzip'

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
con.close()
```

I used boto3/psycopg2 to write [CSV_Loader_For_Redshift](https://github.com/redshift-tools/redshift-csv-loader)

Comment: To use psycopg2, do we need to add VPC to the Lambda Function?

Answer (score 1):

Using psycopyg2 & get_cluster_credentials

Prerequisites -

- IAM ROLE attached to respective User

  IAM Role with get_cluster_credentials policy [LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-iam-credentials-role-permissions.html)
- On cloud (EC2) with appropriate IAM Role attached

The below code will work only if you deploying it on a PC/VM where a user's AWS Credentials are already configured [ CLI - aws configure ] OR
you are on an instance in the same Account,VPC.

1. Have a config.ini file -

   ```
    [Redshift]

    port = 3389

    username = please_enter_username

    database_name = please_database-name

    cluster_id = please_enter_cluster_id_name

    url = please_enter_cluster_endpoint_url

    region = us-west-2
   ```
2. My Redshift_connection.py

   ```
    import logging

    import psycopg2

    import boto3

    import ConfigParser


    def db_connection():
       logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

       parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

       parser.read('config.ini')

       RS_PORT = parser.get('Redshift','port')

       RS_USER = parser.get('Redshift','username')

       DATABASE = parser.get('Redshift','database_name')

       CLUSTER_ID = parser.get('Redshift','cluster_id')

       RS_HOST = parser.get('Redshift','url')

       REGION_NAME = parser.get('Redshift','region')

       client = boto3.client('redshift',region_name=REGION_NAME)

       cluster_creds = client.get_cluster_credentials(DbUser=RS_USER,
                                                   DbName=DATABASE,
                                                   ClusterIdentifier=CLUSTER_ID,
                                                   AutoCreate=False)

    try:
      conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host=RS_HOST,
        port=RS_PORT,
        user=cluster_creds['DbUser'],
        password=cluster_creds['DbPassword'],
        database=DATABASE
      )

      return conn
    except psycopg2.Error:
      logger.exception('Failed to open database connection.')
      print "Failed"
   ```
3. Query Execution script -

   ```
    from Redshift_Connection import db_connection

    def executescript(redshift_cursor):
        query = "SELECT * FROM <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLENAME>"
        cur=redshift_cursor
        cur.execute(query)

    conn = db_connection()
    conn.set_session(autocommit=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    executescript(cursor)
    conn.close()
   ```